# How to extract a self extracting exe from commandline

Tags: windows, installation

Is there a way to extract a self extracting exe from commandline in windows?

I have a self extracting exe which is of type RAR. I want to extract the contents of this RAR only with the help of windows and not using any other tools (like 7zip, Unrar etc) which helps to extract. Also, I want to do it from the command line only.

Are there any utilities in windows which I can use to extract the self extracting exe file from commandline?

Comment: If it is self extracting, what's the problem?

Comment: It is self extracting and runs fine in UI mode but I want to extract that the same in silent mode. I mean I do not want to get the window but the I want the contents of exe file to be extracted to specified location.

Comment: Yes, and what is the problem with doing that?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Windows does not ship with any command-line extraction tools for third-party formats.

Comment: If windows does not support directly then is their any other way which can used to extract the contents of the self extracting exe (type RAR) from commandline. Like any script (may be a vbs) which would do the job of extraction.

Comment: I thought you didn't want to use any other tools?  If you can use a script, why can't you use the command-line version of unrar?

Comment: I know this is a pretty old question, but it's a top Google result for some search phrases, so I wanted to add this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/912203/ -- namely, if the self-extracting archive is a .exe and is published by MS, it has a set of acceptable CLI arguments, one of which is "/extract:path", so you could say `/extract:C:\Temp` to dump the contents to `C:\Temp` on your computer.

Answer (score 20):

You might be able to get the self-extacting RAR archive to do what you want with one or more of the following RAR SFX (self-extracting archive) options:

> GUI self-extracting modules support following command line
>         switches:
>
> ```
>   -d<path>     set the destination path
>   -p<pwd>      specify a password
>   -s           silent mode, hide all
>   -s1          same as -s
>   -s2          silent mode, hide start dialog
>   -sp<par>     specify parameters for setup program
> ```

I'm not sure if any of these options will suppress running a setup program that the SFX is configured to run.

Comment: These options don't suppress or replace the options configured in SFX. If you try to extract a SFX exe configured to extract in Temp folder in a different folder (with "-d<path>" argument), it won't work.

https://www.winrar-france.fr/winrar_instructions_for_use/source/html/HELPGUISFXCmd.htm

Answer (score 6):

Download UnRar for windows (freeware) from [this link](http://www.rarlab.com/rar/unrarw32.exe). It in itself is a self extracting archive, which when installed will give you the actual unrar.exe. You can then use unrar.exe to extract files from the command line.

Comment: [...] only with the help of windows and not using any other tools (like 7zip, Unrar etc)[...]

Answer (score 1):

Use unzip utility from http://www.info-zip.org/. It is an open source and binaries are available for all os flavors.

unzip command: `unzip.exe sample.zip -d extract_folder`

Download latest windows executable at ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/win32/.
After downloading the binary like 'unz552xn-x64.exe', run it in command line, it will give a set of files including unzip.exe. since unzip.exe does not have any dependency other files can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

**For others that are looking for the answer to this.**

Download the trial version or purchase WinRAR. Right click the files you want to package and select add to archive.

Check "create sfx archive" on the General tab, this will give you the file.exe

Select the "sfx options" on the Advanced tab, under the Modes tab select "hide all".
If you don't want the extracted files to show or stay after your program/script has run then "Unpack to temporary folder" under this same tab.

Under the Setup tab in the "run after extraction" put the program or script you would like to run.

Once file(s) have been packaged you will have a file called file.exe. (Note:File will be what you named the sfx archive). From command line type file.exe and it will extract to the temp location (if you selected that) and run the program/script that you specified. Once the program/script closes the folder in the temp location will be removed.

**Notes:**

If running from a WinPe CD or otherwise similar bootable media do not use "Unpack to Temporary Folder".

WinRAR only has to be on the computer making the sfx archive. Once the sfx archive is made you won't need it to extract the files.

Comment: -1.  The OP was dealing with an existing self-extracting archive.  He did not ask how to create one.

Comment: I assumed since he was asking how to extract a self extracting archive (with his requirements) that he didn't make the archive and that it should be repackaged to do what he wants.

Comment: So are you saying there's a configuration setup step that enables the self extracting zip exe file to operate either in UI and/or command line mode?